# Rockmongo was not found on local server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I've install Rockmongo on my Ubuntu 12.04. 
I've followed [this](http://blog.khairulazam.net/2013/05/19/install-rockmongo-on-ubuntu/) link to install.

After all the steps done, whenever I hit `localhost/rockmongo` it gives me the error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /rockmongo was not found on this server.
```

Comment: So what was the problem? Did you fixed it?

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed that. For the later versions of ubuntu > 12.04, (e.g. 12.04.x ) the pecl was not upgraded. So, I've installed the 12.04 64bit version and now its working.

Comment: I have to install rockmongo in ubuntu 14.04. Plz help me.